# pthread_mutex based inter process communication not working

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I am currently trying to sinchronize two processess in Linux using the pthread_mutex model.

Here's the code I am working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf ("starting process\n");

    if (_POSIX_THREAD_PROCESS_SHARED == -1) {
        printf ("shared mutex is not supported!\r\n");
    }

    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutex_t shm_mutex;


    if (pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr) != 0)
        printf ("init attr error!\r\n");
    if (pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL) != 0)
        printf ("set type error!\r\n");
    if (pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) != 0)
        printf ("set shared error!\r\n");

    int value;
    if (pthread_mutexattr_getpshared(&attr, &value) != 0 || value != PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) {
        printf ("mutex is not shared!\r\n");
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&shm_mutex, &attr) != 0)
        printf ("mutex init error!\r\n");

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {

        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&shm_mutex) != 0)
            printf ("lock error!\r\n");

        printf ("begin run %d\r\n", i);
        sleep(10);
        printf ("end run %d\r\n", i);

        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm_mutex) != 0)
            printf ("unlock error!\r\n");

        sleep(1); // sleep 1 second
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&shm_mutex);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run two separate processes, the begin/end logic doesm't work.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: I believe you need to allocate the mutex in shared memory for there to be any possibility of inter-process sharing. There is no way in your code for the processes to identify which mutex they'd be sharing.

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to allocate `shm_mutex` in shared memory yourself. See `man shm_overview`. The flag merely means you're allowed to do this with the mutex.

See [this reference](http://web.archive.org/web/20150524005553/http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch05-ipc.pdf) for more detailed information.